# Extract 3 numbers from string and put them into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract 3 numbers from string and put them into variables

This is the html

```
<a href="javascript:theNumbers( 09222004, 05232015, '4815162342' );">Click Me</a>
```

I got the href string with jQuery

```
$('a').attr('href')
```

and the result is

```
javascript:theNumbers( 09222004, 05232015, '4815162342' );
```

I want to extract each value (09222004 and 05232015 and 4815162342) to variable so I can use each number in different process

Comment: Are you sure you need to split the string? It looks like your code is supposed to be calling a function `theNumbers` with three arguments. In that case, just get the arguments from the function itself.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes I want to use each number in different process, btw I can't change the source because I use my code in chrome extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a data-numbers="'09222004, 05232015, 4815162342'">Click Me</a>
```

to  get value

```
var numbers =$('a').attr('data-numbers').split(',');
```

this return an array

['09222004', '05232015', '4815162342']

Comment: I can't change the source because I use my code in chrome extension

Comment: use replace:  numbers=numbers.replace("javascript:theNumbers(","").replace(")","").split(',')

Comment: see my update here   http://jsfiddle.net/91yp5uaf/2/    (remove split from first line)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot, I just have a tiny problem with the last number I need to remove quotes http://jsfiddle.net/91yp5uaf/3/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, i hope it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // get href text attribute
  var mString = $('a').attr('href');
  // get the text between ()
  var mResult = mString.match(/\((.*)\)/);
  // split mResult
  var numbers = mResult[1].split(',');
  // show the result
  for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    $("#numbers").append('Number ' + i + ' is ' + numbers[i] + '<br>');    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:theNumbers( 09222004, 05232015, '4815162342' );">Click Me</a>
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `str.split([separator[, limit]])` will help you here, brackets then commas.

[Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the elements of the array of size 3 you end up with